# Submitting CI form without page reloading

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation

So I have a controller within CI for updating the title of a Shoutcast server.

I'd like be able to run the form, without the page reloading.

The applicable controller / view is below;

**Controller**

```
                function update_title()
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('song', 'Song', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>', '</div>'
                );

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                    /* $this->load->view('header');
                    $this->load->view('radio/panel'); // Failed validation
                    $this->load->view('footer'); */
                    $this->broadcast();
                }
                else
                {
                $data   =  $this->data;
                $ip     =  $data[1]; // Server Address 
                $port   =  $data[2]; // Server Port
                $pass   =  $data[4]; // Admin Password
        //  -------------------------------------------------
                $song = $this->input->post('song');     
                $song = urlencode($song); 
                $song = str_replace("+", "%20", $song);
                $fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,4);
                if (!$fp) {
                    print "Error: cant get server, please check that server is online";
                } else {
                    fputs($fp, "GET /admin.cgi?pass=" . $pass . "&mode=updinfo&song=" . $song . " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
                    fputs($fp, "User-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");
                    fclose($fp);
                    $song = str_replace("%20", "+", $song);
                    $song = urldecode($song);
                }
                    $this->load->view('header');
                    $this->load->view('radio/title_updated');
                    $this->load->view('footer');
                }
            }
```

**View**

```
<?php
            $input_title = array(
                'name'  => 'song',
                'id'    => 'song',
                'size'  => 30,
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Artist(s) - Show Name'
            );

            $input_submit = array(
                'name'  => 'submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                'type'  => 'submit'
            );

            ?>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="row well">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                <?php
                echo form_open('radio/update_title');
                echo '<div class="input-group">';
                echo form_input($input_title);
                echo '<span class="input-group-btn">';
                echo form_button($input_submit, '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-1x"></i>');
                //echo form_submit('submit', 'Update Show Title', "class='btn btn-primary'");
                echo '</span></div>';
                echo form_close();
                ?>
                </div>


                </div>

                </div>

            </div> <!-- /container -->
```

This all works perfectly, however as I say the page is refreshing. I've tried following a number of guides on this, however regardless of what I try, the page reloads.

Can someone please offer some advice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you have tried working with AJAX?  It's very important to either call `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` at the end of your `submit` event listener or it will try to submit and refresh anyway.

Comment: Hello Joseph, I have indeed. What you see above is essentially the code without my attempts. I've had this working before perfectly prior to using CI, however everything I would do before does not seem to be yielding the desired results /sadface.

Comment: Show your attempts instead of showing the php controller code. Can do this very simply using jQery but you need to show where the problems occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is primarily client-side at this point.  You should never see the page refresh if you're properly calling an AJAX function.  Even if it errors out, it would die silently (or show an error in the javascript console).  So lets put together a call for your function.

In your PHP, you will have to add an ID to your form.  This is important to key off of when we build the jQuery around the AJAX call

```
echo form_open('radio/update_title', array('id' => 'update-title'));
```

Now we can start building the javascript.  jQuery has some really nice features for calling ajax and we'll use them to full effect.

```
$('#update-title').on('submit', function(event){ // make sure you pass the event param

    // get the form values and serialize them
    var values = $(this).serializeArray();

    // lets make our call to the server
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(values), // get it in the right format
        error: function(data, status, error) {
            // handle your errors here
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            // show your validation or display success message
        },
        complete: function(data, status) {
            // other post-process stuff regardless of success
        }
    });

    // here's the important part to prevent the page load
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I would highly recommend either detecting AJAX or using a different method other than `update_title` for your AJAX request because of the `$this->load->view` calls in `update_title`.  Whatever you echo out is what you will need to work with back on the client side, and if you echo out a full HTML document, it's going to be a mess.  I suggest validating server-side and then returning your success, error, or validation error messages with JSON and not loading views. **NOTE: this is untested code**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've been reading up as you suggested and think I understand exactly what I need to do now!

Comment: @Gordon_ Glad to hear it.  Good luck and happy coding! :)